# Not able to connect django1.11 with oracle11g

Tags: django, oracle, oracle11g

I am not able to migrate project in linux. Dependecy:cx-Oracle==7.2.0
Django==1.11,oracle11g and python3.I am trying to connect with a server database.

I removed a line `self.cursor.numbersAsStrings = True` from **/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py** to resolve this error:

> AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'numbersAsStrings'

BUT now, after python manage.py migrate, I am getting the following error.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 250, in apply_migration
    self.recorder.record_applied(migration.app_label, migration.name)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in record_applied
    self.migration_qs.create(app=app, name=name)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 393, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 922, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 961, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1060, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1106, in execute_sql
    return self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_id(cursor)
  File "/home/arima/work/sunlife_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/operations.py", line 245, in fetch_returned_insert_id
    return int(cursor._insert_id_var.getvalue())
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

I need help to connect my db to django project.